# adding postgres constraint for may to many mandatory relationship

Tags: postgresql, constraints

I have two tables and CANDIDATE and DEFAULT_VALUES .

```
CANDIDATE has id,name columns.
DEFAULT_VALUES has value1,value2,value3 columns.
```

A Candidate has many default values.
**The DEFAULT values should be defined for all the candidates in CANDIDATE table.**

For example , I have 5 candidate in my CANDIDATE table.

When the user adds default values then the database should ensure that all 5 candidates default values are entered.

For example , the user may enter default value only for 3 users and miss to add it for other 2 users.

How to add a constraint for this?

I have just added a foreign key reference in DEFAULT_VALUES table which refers the id of CANDIDATE table.

Thanks

Comment: Because postgres only supports tuple constraints, I think you need to stick with your `value1`, `value2`,...`value5` approach; simply declare each as `NOT NULL`. Unless you want to write a trigger...

Comment: I'm not 100% certain I understand your tables. Is your `DEFAULT_VALUES` tables missing a `candidate_id` column? So for each row in `CANDIDATE`, you want to have 3 defaultvalues, and if the user adds a candidate, you want to force him to add the default values too?

Comment: just make all columns in DEFAULT_VALUES `NOT NULL`

Comment: @Solarflare , yes , you are right . How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JavaUser You cannot do this with your current data model (at least if you want to have a foreign key from that missing `candidate_id` column in `DEFAULT_VALUES` to the `CANDIDATE` table). To enforce this rule by the data model, you have to merge your two tables. So your `candidate` table would look like: `CANDIDATE (id, name, defaultvalue1, defaultvalue2, defaultvalue3)` with all columns `not null`. Now, as requested, you cannot add a candidate without default values.